# why is there more than one python 2 command in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, python, gnome-terminal, symbolic-link

so while playing with some aliases I realized that there are three python commands (without taking into account the python 3 commands) in the terminal:

- python
- python2
- python2.7

So my question is why is this the case? Why do we need three? I understand the need to have a generic one (python) and the need to have another one to distinguish python3 from python2 but the rest I do not know.

Furthermore, how can I see if they are linked to the same file (symbolic link)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`python` is the default interpreter used by the distribution. It may (or may not<sup>**1**</sup>) point to python3 in the future.

`python2` is the default Python 2 interpreter (that is the same as above if `python` points to `python2`, not otherwise). It points to the current stable/supported interpreter.

`python2.7` is the specific interpreter --- you can have for example `python2.7` as the current one, and a `python2.1` that you need to check compatibility matters.

To see all of them:

```
[romano:~] % ls -l /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 jul 22  2014 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 jul 22  2014 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3345416 jun 22 20:51 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

So in your scripts  — in the shebang<sup>**2**</sup> — you use `python` if you want to use the default interpreter for the distribution (and if you want total future safety you have your script both working in version 2 *and* 3, but see note 1 below);   `python2` or `python3` if you need version 2 *or* 3 specifically, but it's ok using the default one the distribution offers (recommended); `python2.7` if you *need* that specific version and you prefer that your script fails if it's not available.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> I *think* it will never change to point to `python3`, it's too dangerous. But well, I have no crystal balls...

<sup>**2**</sup> this is the first line of the executable scripts that for Python should look like

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
```